# Oracle SQL - Update column data using MINUS operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've this sql query

```
(select x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d
from tableX x
where x.a IS NOT NULL
minus 
select y.a, y.b, y.c, y.d
from tableY y);
```

The above query returns me all tableX data, that is different from tableY. Multiple tuples are returned

**Evidence:**

When i run above query i get this result:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 65 |
| 2 | 66 | 333 |

When i select data from tableY i get this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 54 | 65 |
| 2 | 88 | 567 |

tableY data is the correct data, so i want to update all tuples that are returned from the first query(the one with MINUS clause) with the data from tableY.

The expected result, after the update clause, when i select data from tableX should be:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 54 | 65 |
| 2 | 88 | 567 |

What is the most eficcient way to do this UPDATE clause?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Say your query returned the row (17, 54, 17), is that tableX row expected to be updated to (1, 54, 65)? How do you know which tableX row to update to which tableY row?

Comment: "a" column is primary key

Comment: Does b or c contain any null values?

Comment: yes, that's why, in the first query, i use "where x.a IS NOT NULL"
just to clarify, both tables have the same info, but tableX table is "outdated", that's why i only want to update the tuples that i get from the first query

Comment: `where x.a IS NOT NULL` confused me, since primary keys don't allow null values.

Comment: yeah, my bad, the other columns have null values, a column not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On oracle I find the MERGE syntax much more usable than the UPDATE syntax...

```
MERGE INTO
  tablex   x
USING
  tabley   y
    ON (y.a = x.a)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET
    x.b = y.b,
    x.c = y.c
  WHERE
    LNNVL(x.b = y.b)
    OR
    LNNVL(x.c = y.c)
```

Edit: added where clause to avoid redundant updates, following comment below.

Comment: Are rows where x.b = y.b and x.c = y.c included in the transaction?

Comment: @jarlh Added a where clause to the `WHEN MATCHED` to avoid that scenario.

Comment: this solution solved my question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablex
set (b, c) = (select b, c from tabley where tabley.a = tablex.a)
where exists (select 1 from tabley where tabley.a = tablex.a);
```

To keep transaction size down, add xb <> yb or xc <> yc:

```
update tablex
set (b, c) = (select b, c from tabley where tabley.a = tablex.a)
where exists (select 1 from tabley
              where tabley.a = tablex.a
                and (LNNVL(tabley.b = tablex.b) or LNNVL(tabley.c = tablex.c)));
```